# Details of JDBC PreparedStatement.executeQuery()

Tags: jdbc

When we execute SQL queries using PreparedStatement (as described here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html), what exactly does the executeQuery() method do, if we use for example a database like SQL Server or Postgres? Does it convert the SQL query directly into a set of database operations, or does it make a network call to a database server that translates the SQL query to the database operations?
This is more generally a question about how databases like SQL Server work. I'm just wondering if they're running on separate servers than the ones calling executeQuery().

Comment: What do you mean with "translates query"? The query is prepared on the server, and then executed on the server with the set of parameters you provide. However, details vary per database. There could be JDBC drivers where the driver compiles the query and performs low-level operations on the database server, but that would be unusual for database where SQL is the normal query language.

Comment: I mean taking the SQL query and transforming it into a set of low level operations to execute it. I'm just wondering if that runs on the same server that calls executeQuery() or on a dedicated database server.

Answer (score 0):

The implementations details vary per database system, but in general JDBC drivers for RDBMSes that uses SQL as their native query language will work as follows:

1. When `Connection.prepareStatement(...)` is executed, the query is sent to the database server for compilation
2. On `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`, the driver sends an execute command together with the collected parameter values, and the database server executes the statement compiled earlier using those parameter values.

In other words, the driver is not concerned with low-level operations on the database server, but will just send a 'compile' and 'execute-with-parameters' command to the database server, and the database server takes care of the low-level operations.

And to be clear, not all drivers work this way. For example, the MySQL Connector/J by default 'compiles' the statement locally (determines the number of parameters), and on execute it will inline the parameter values (with proper escaping) into the statement, and then send a SQL string with literal values instead of parameters for execution on the database server. However, in that case, the database server is still responsible for determining and performing the necessary low-level operations.

On the other hand, it is entirely possible that a driver for some NoSQL database (or other type of datastore) will translate a SQL query into low-level operations on that datastore.

Comment: thank you for your reply. You say "the query is sent to the database server for compilation", so if the database is for example SQL Server, there would be a dedicated server for it? does that database server run in the background in the OS? I don't think we need to manually run the database server ourselves

Comment: @alfer SQL Server is - unless you're using SQL Server localdb (which is not supported by the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver) - a server process that accepts connections of clients and does the necessary work to manage the data, handle inserts, selects and transactions, etc. This is how most database systems work.

Comment: when you say "SQL Server is", you mean it does run in the background? and so most database systems run in the background without manually starting them

Comment: @alfer Yes, usually database servers are started on startup of the host where the database is installed. They listen on a port, accepting connections, and then do the necessary work for those connections.

Comment: do you know if it is the same for message brokers like RabbitMQ? do they run independently (and we don't need to start them manually) or are they part of application servers?

Comment: @alfer Yes, this usually also applies to other server-based services like message brokers.